# What is the correct process to switch between ADFs?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I have a project which lets the user to select from the ADFs existing on a Tango-enabled device, to allow them to correctly localize in a number of different spaces.

My code (Unity 5.5, C#, Farandole SDK) essentially performs manual Tango startup with a null AreaDescription as the entry flow. If the user then selects an ADF, I'm calling TangoApplication.Shutdown() then TangoApplication.Startup(newArea).

in Eisa, this works. In Farandole, I get a permissions failure.
if, using Farandole, I explicitly request permissions (after the Shutdown) and wait for the permissions response to come back before calling Startup, the system appears to re-localise against the new ADF, but the Tango system is re-registering callbacks every time around through Startup without unregistering them, meaning I get my callbacks called multiple times for each ADF that I switch to.

What is the correct process to switch between ADFs? Should a shutdown be required before calling Startup, and if so, what is the correct way to shutdown the TangoApplication to avoid multiple callbacks?

Answer (score -1):

I am interested in this answer too. The way I would do it, is reload the scene with the new ADF, just like it is done in the AreaLearning example, so TangoManager and TangoPoseController are reset.

Comment: That should be a comment as it doesn't seem like you're very certain that your answer is an actual solution.

Comment: Actually I am suggesting something to switch from ADFs that works so I disagree with you. By the way, and thanks for the -1 mate, we are not all StackOverFlow guru of comments vs. answer sections, my bad.